# Retrieve relationship fields on object output

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8

When outputting the client object to JSON I also need to include the region fields, how do I go about doing this?  I've tried eager loading but the output doesn't include the fields.

Model(s)

```
Client
public function Office(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models|offices', 'ref_id', 'OfficeID')->where('DB', '=', $this->RemoteDatabase);
}

Office
public function region(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Regions', 'regions_id');
}
```

Code to get the client

```
$ModelOBJ = Clients::where('ClientCode', 'LIKE', $term)
    ->orderBy('ClientName', 'ASC');
if ((clone $ModelOBJ)->count() > 0){
    $ClientData = $ModelOBJ->with('Office.Region:HRName')->get();
    return response()->json(['code' => '200', 'Client' => $ClientData, 'querieis'=> \DB::getQueryLog()]);
}
```

This returns the following

```
    code    "200"
    Client  [ {…}, {…} ]
    querieis    [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
    0   Object { query: "select count(*) as aggregate from [Clients] where [ClientCode] LIKE ?", time: 56.64, bindings: […] }
    query   "select count(*) as aggregate from [Clients] where [ClientCode] LIKE ?"
    bindings    [ "test" ]
    0   "test"
    time    56.64
    1   Object { query: "select * from [Clients] where [ClientCode] LIKE ? order by [ClientName] asc", time: 59.12, bindings: […] }
    query   "select * from [Clients] where [ClientCode] LIKE ? order by [ClientName] asc"
    bindings    [ "test" ]
    0   "test"
    time    59.12
    2   Object { query: "select * from [Offices] where [Active] = ? and [DB] is null and [Offices].[ref_id] in (?, ?)", time: 2.55, bindings: […] }
    query   "select * from [Offices] where [Active] = ? and [DB] is null and [Offices].[ref_id] in (?, ?)"
    bindings    [ "Y", "1", "5" ]
    time    2.55
```

Answer (score 1):

When loading specific fields in eager loading you should also select the identifier of the record which is used to map the related records. So in your case `(belongsTo)` its `id` primary key of `Region`

```
$ModelOBJ->with('Office.Region:id,HRName')->get();
```

[**See Eager Loading Specific Columns**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

> When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.